# Using feols() vs plm() vs lm() in panel regressions in R

Tags: regression, modeling, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am using panel data at the district level. My outcome variable is the share of employed individuals in a given district. I am regressing this variable on a binary treatment dummy called "treat", which is also at the district level. I am also adding year and district fixed effects.

I used three different methods as shown below in `reg1`, `reg2`, and `reg3`, which use `feols()`, `plm()`, and `lm()` functions, respectively. While using the `lm()` function, I add the `factor()` function to include the fixed effects.

As the results below show, the coefficients on `treat` are very different in terms of direction, magnitude, and significance level. I'm trying to understand which function suits my current situation, but also to understand the general situations on when to use these functions and their differences.

```
library(fixest)
reg1 <- feols(emp ~ treat, data, panel.id = ~year + district)
                Estimate   Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)
      treat    -0.066819   0.012030   -5.55442   1.4402e-03 ** 


library(plm)
reg2 <- plm(emp ~ treat, index = c("year", "district"), data = data, model = "within", effect = "twoways")
               Estimate    Std. Error  t-value   Pr(>|t|)    
      treat   -0.0370409   0.0067479  -5.4892    4.3e-08 *


reg3 <- lm(formula = emp ~ treat + factor(year) + factor(district), data = data)

               Estimate    Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)    
      treat    0.0060141   0.0130635   0.460     0.645280
```

Comment: The code looks okay to me. Could you share a subset of the data? If not, what kind of data are you working with? Is this repeated cross-sectional data? Are covariates excluded?

Comment: @ThomasBilach, how can I share a subset of the data? I'm using cross-sectional individual-level data, but these regressions aggregate observations at the district level, so basically, it's a district-level panel. Covariates are excluded in all three regressions for now.

Comment: Is your question about the differences in the code or the differences in the regression types?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `feols` only identifies the panel units via `panel.id`, without then also running a fixed-effects regression. To get one, specify the fixed effects as follows:

```
library(plm)
library(fixest)

data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")

plm.reg <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "within", effect = "twoways")
fixest.reg <- feols(inv ~ value + capital | firm + year, data = Grunfeld)
lm.panelreg <- lm(inv ~ value + capital + factor(year) + factor(firm), data = Grunfeld)


summary(plm.reg)
summary(fixest.reg)
summary(lm.panelreg)
```

To see that `feols` runs a plain pooled OLS regression in "your" specification, consider

```
fixest.reg2 <- feols(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, panel.id = ~firm + year)
lm.linreg <- lm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld)

summary(fixest.reg2)
summary(lm.linreg)
```

Why `lm` returns yet other data in your code (in mine we get the same results for all three) is as of yet unclear to me. Is your panel balanced?

Comment: Hi Christoph, thank you so much for the detailed response! I saw that you didn't mention the fixed effects variables for the PLM regression. Although it worked for the Grunfield data you used, it is showing an error for the data I'm using [Error in plm.fit(data, model, effect, random.method, random.models, random.dfcor, : empty model]. Also, I think my PLM regression with my code above and your fixest regression are giving the same results. That's something! The lm regression still gives different estimates. And, yes, my data is a balanced panel at the district level.

Comment: I think plm uses the first columns to identify by default. If the code does not work on your data, that seems to strengthen @ThomasBilach's point that looking at the data would be relevant.

Comment: Thanks! I think we found the error. For some reason, the panel wasn't balanced. Maybe that's causing the issue.

Comment: Wansbeek, T.J. and A. Kapteyn, 1989, Estimation of the error components model with incomplete panels, Journal of Econometrics 41, 341–361 could be relevant to spell out details,